# Count milliseconds between two times

Tags: java, algorithm, time

I need an algorithm that counts milliseconds between these times

```
HH:MM:SS,MS  --> HH:MM:SS,MS

00:08:50,800 --> 00:08:55,250
```

I write a java code for 4 times but I think I did not understand the idea, I searched for it but all solutions used a libraries and I do not want to use a library.

Here is the java code I wrote, but it does not give me correct offset

```
private int findOffset(Time t1, Time t2) {
        int offset = 0;
        int diffHH = (t2.getHH() - t1.getHH());
        int diffMM = (t2.getMM() - t1.getMM());
        int diffSS = (t2.getSS() - t1.getSS());
        int diffMS = (t2.getMS() - t1.getMS());
        if (diffHH != 0) {
            if (diffHH < 0) {
                diffHH = 24 - t1.getHH() + t2.getHH();
            }
            offset += (3600000 * diffHH);
        }

        if (diffMM != 0) {
            if (diffMM < 0) {
                diffMM = 60 - t1.getMM() + t2.getMM();
            }
            offset += (60000 * diffMM);
        }
        if (diffSS != 0) {
            if (diffSS < 0) {
                diffSS = 60 - t1.getSS() + t2.getSS();
            }
            offset += (1000 * diffSS);
        }

        if (diffMS != 0) {

            if (diffMS < 0) {
                diffMS =  t1.getMS() + t2.getMS();
            }

            offset -= diffMS;
        }

        return offset;
    }
```

here is another code

```
private int findOffset2(Time t1, Time t2) {
        int offset = 0;
        int hh1 = t1.getHH(), hh2 = t2.getHH();
        int mm1 = t1.getMM(), mm2 = t2.getMM();
        int ss1 = t1.getSS(), ss2 = t2.getSS();
        int ms1 = t1.getMS(), ms2 = t2.getMS();

        while (hh1 != hh2 || mm1 != mm2
                || ss1 != ss2 || ms1 != ms2) {
            offset++;

            ms1++;
            while (ms1 >= 1000) {
                ss1++;

                while (ss1 >= 60) {
                    ss1 -= 60;
                    mm1++;
                }

                while (mm1 >= 60) {
                    mm1 -= 60;
                    hh1++;
                }

                ms1 -= 1000;
            }

            if(hh1 == hh2 && mm1 == mm2
                && ss1 == ss2 && ms1 == ms2){
                  System.out.println("test");  
                }

        }

        return offset;
    }
```

Comment: Then you should add your code to the question, even if it appears to be not working or otherwise would feel dumb to post, but do it. And tag your question with Java.

Comment: calculate only miliseconds and then convert them to hours, minute and second and milisecond and print that in above format

Comment: @yacc I'm not asking for a code I just want a description or an algorithm that clarify how to do it, so I can try another method.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim you did not understand me, the time format is the input and the milliseconds is the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to convert Time to ms and just return the diff :

```
private int timeToMs(Time t) {
    return t.getHH() * 60 * 60 * 1000 + t.getMM() * 60 * 1000 + t.getSS() * 1000 + t.getMS();
}

private int findOffset(Time begin, Time end) {
    return timeToMs(end) - timeToMs(begin);
}
```

EDIT : This answer assumes that the given Times are in the same day.

Comment: If start=23:55:00.000 and end=00:10:00.000 you'll end up with a negative number instead of a 15-minute interval.

Comment: Yes, but how can we know that there is only one day between the two Times ?

Comment: That is a good point. The OP hasn't specified the requirements properly. But if you take it to the extreme, your answer may not be correct even for times like 10:11:12.345 to 10:11:13.678. It may be an interval of 1333 milliseconds, but how do you know it's not 1 day + 1333 ms, or 2 days + 1333 ms?

Comment: Haha you're right too. Maybe if op wants a result in ms, it's because there is not much time between the begin and the end (so your first comment can make sense).

Comment: @senerh yes it is in the same day

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes it is in the same day

Answer (score 2):

```
private int findOffset(Time t1, Time t2) {
    int hh1 = t1.getHH(), hh2 = t2.getHH();
    int mm1 = t1.getMM(), mm2 = t2.getMM();
    int ss1 = t1.getSS(), ss2 = t2.getSS();
    int ms1 = t1.getMS(), ms2 = t2.getMS();

    int offset = ((((hh2 - hh1) * 60) + (mm2 - mm1)) * 60) + (ss2 - ss1)) * 1000 + (ms2 - ms1);

    if (offset < 0)
        offset += 24*60*60*1000;
    return offset;
}
```

Note that this always gives an answer in the range 0 to 23h 59m 59.999ms. The question didn't specify any dates for the two given times; therefore, the real answer could be + or - N days (where N can be any integer).

Comment: this code is correct also, thank you but I chose the small code.